# Browser-based debugging and performance testing software for react application

Tags: reactjs, performance, google-chrome-devtools, profiling

I am knee on learning how to do Browser-based debugging and performance testing software for react application

what all the tools to use and also what are the metrics to consider for effective react application

Any article or pointers will be to explore more

Answer (score 0):

From my information You can use  [Chrome lighthouse](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/lighthouse/overview/#:%7E:text=Lighthouse%20is%20an%20open%2Dsource,web%20apps%2C%20SEO%20and%20more.) or [GTmetrix website](https://gtmetrix.com/) for performance
and for debugging you use [react-devtools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en) extension and if you are using webstorm you can use [its built-in tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en)

or [webpack devTool](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/) with source map to see and edit react components in the browser